# Pyspark Dataframe substract rows from the same column?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following example as a pyspark dataframe:

| Timeframe | Person | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-21 8:00:00 | Lisa | Working |
| 2022-06-21 8:30:00 | Joseph | Homework |
| 2022-06-21 8:00:00 | Michael | Gardening |
| 2022-06-21 9:00:00 | Joseph | Rowing |
| 2022-06-21 9:00:00 | Lisa | Working |
| 2022-06-21 9:15:00 | Joseph | Football |
| 2022-06-21 10:00:00 | Joseph | Dancing |
| 2022-06-21 10:00:00 | Lisa | Watering |
| 2022-06-21 10:30:00 | Joseph | Gaming |

I would like to calculate how long each activity for each person lasted. For example create a new column like this:

| Timeframe | Person | Activity | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-21 8:00:00 | Lisa | Working | 01:00:00 |
| 2022-06-21 8:30:00 | Joseph | Homework | 00:30:00 |
| 2022-06-21 8:00:00 | Michael | Gardening | 01:15:00 |
| 2022-06-21 9:00:00 | Joseph | Rowing | 01:00:00 |
| 2022-06-21 9:00:00 | Lisa | Working | 01:00:00 |
| 2022-06-21 9:15:00 | Michael | Football | 01:45:00 |
| 2022-06-21 10:00:00 | Joseph | Dancing | N/A |
| 2022-06-21 10:00:00 | Lisa | Watering | N/A |
| 2022-06-21 10:30:00 | Michael | Gaming | N/A |

I need to substract the Timeframe row for each person separatly and create a new column. There is no pause in between. How can it be done in Pyspark or alternatively in Pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can calculate the time difference in seconds and convert it to the required format.

Using a subset of your data for example.

```
data_ls = [
    ('2022-06-21 8:00:00', 'Lisa', 'Working'),
    ('2022-06-21 8:30:00', 'Joe', 'HW'),
    ('2022-06-21 8:00:00', 'Mike', 'Gardening'),
    ('2022-06-21 9:00:00', 'Joe', 'Rowing'),
    ('2022-06-21 9:00:00', 'Lisa', 'Working')
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['ts', 'name', 'activity']). \
    withColumn('ts', func.col('ts').cast('timestamp'))

# +-------------------+----+---------+
# |                 ts|name| activity|
# +-------------------+----+---------+
# |2022-06-21 08:00:00|Lisa|  Working|
# |2022-06-21 08:30:00| Joe|       HW|
# |2022-06-21 08:00:00|Mike|Gardening|
# |2022-06-21 09:00:00| Joe|   Rowing|
# |2022-06-21 09:00:00|Lisa|  Working|
# +-------------------+----+---------+
```

We can take a `lead()` (next timestamp) for each `name` and subtract it from current timestamp to get the duration in seconds. Using the seconds, we can calculate minutes, hours, or even format it as a time string.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('duration_sec', 
               func.coalesce(func.lead('ts').over(wd.partitionBy('name').orderBy('ts')).cast('long') - func.col('ts').cast('long'), 
                             func.lit(0)
                             )
               ). \
    withColumn('duration_min', func.col('duration_sec') / 60). \
    withColumn('duration_time', func.from_unixtime('duration_sec', format='HH:mm:ss')). \
    show()

# +-------------------+----+---------+------------+------------+-------------+
# |                 ts|name| activity|duration_sec|duration_min|duration_time|
# +-------------------+----+---------+------------+------------+-------------+
# |2022-06-21 08:30:00| Joe|       HW|        1800|        30.0|     00:30:00|
# |2022-06-21 09:00:00| Joe|   Rowing|           0|         0.0|     00:00:00|
# |2022-06-21 08:00:00|Mike|Gardening|           0|         0.0|     00:00:00|
# |2022-06-21 08:00:00|Lisa|  Working|        3600|        60.0|     01:00:00|
# |2022-06-21 09:00:00|Lisa|  Working|           0|         0.0|     00:00:00|
# +-------------------+----+---------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I get the error  "name 'func' is not defined"

Comment: func is the alias to pyspark sql functions -- `import pyspark.sql.functions as func` `from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd`. feel free to update the alias as per your liking